# Node/Express and MongoDB: Async/Await with Model.create()

Tags: typescript, express, asynchronous, mongoose, async-await

I'm currently working on a MEAN project with TypeScript on the backend. Everything's working fine. However, I was wondering the following code block:

```
TodoSchema.static('createTodo', async (newTodo: ITodo) => {
    return await Todo.create(newTodo)
        .then((result: ITodo) => result)
        .catch((error: MongoError) => error);
});
```

The above code block works fine but it looks a bit redundant for `async/await` I believe. Below is the code block that calls the above function:

```
const result = await Todo.createTodo(newTodo);
    if (result instanceof MongoError) TodoController.resolveErrorResponse(res, result.message, 500, result);
    if ((typeof(result)) === 'undefined' && !result) TodoController.resolveErrorResponse(res, 'Error saving Todo', res.statusCode);
```

Everything returns correctly here. However, as I said that I feel it's a bit redundant, I took out `then/catch` block:

```
TodoSchema.static('createTodo', async (newTodo: ITodo) => {
    return await Todo.create(newTodo);
});
```

and I got this error:

```
(node:1306) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: jaanartc.todos.$slug_1 dup key: { : "test-title" }
```

To my understanding (I might be HORRIBLY wrong here), `return await Todo.create(newTodo)` should return the result of the `create()`. So if I check for `instanceof MongoError`, I think I should be fine.

Please enlighten me. Thank you.

Comment: FYI, there's never a reason for `return await someFunc()`.  It doesn't add anything.  An `async` function already returns a promise and to use the value, the caller has to either use `await` or `.then()` themselves.  So, just `return Todo.create(...).then(...)`.  `await` only works inside the function it is used, not for a return value.  An `async` function is still asynchronous and returns a promise whose resolved value is what you want.  Doing `return await someFunc()` does magically allow the `async` function to directly return the value.  It still returns a promise.

Comment: You are correct. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

In adopting async/await workflow, I think there are two options:

```
TodoSchema.static('createTodo', async (newTodo: ITodo) => {
    return await Todo.create(newTodo);
});

// later on in code
try { const item = await TodoModel.createTodo({...}); }
catch (e) { // do something }
```

Or

```
TodoSchema.static('createTodo', async (newTodo: ITodo): Promise<TodoInstance | null> => {
  try { return await Todo.create(newTodo); }
  catch (e) { return null;  }
});

// later on in code
const item = await TodoModel.createTodo({...});

if (!item) {
  // something went wrong
}

item.remove() // this is safe now
```

I would go with the second approach, because it would be a headache otherwise

Comment: Btw, maybe you would be interested in my fully typed mongoose schema and model workflow https://gist.github.com/rasdaniil/a63fc9ae83819f4587bb498ac10a689f

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have adjusted my code, you can take a look at https://github.com/nartc/jaanartc

Comment: Nice clean code, I've sent a pr there, maybe your would find it usefull